# Type mismatch for variadic generics variable in class __init__ VS method contexts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a type mismatch between the same definition of variadic generic `Union[*HandlerTypes]` used in `__init__` and in `pet_handler` method.

I want strongly typed decorators - I achieve this by using `TypeVarTuple` variadic generics. All seems to work. But there is one last problem - the type mismatch between:

a) `self.handlers: list[Union[*HandlerTypes]] = []`
b) `self.handlers.append(handler_func)`

Though technically the type is the same `Union[*HandlerTypes]` appearantly the difference of the usage context (class init vs method) triggers the pylance error for `self.handlers.append(handler_func)`:

```
Argument of type "Union[*HandlerTypes@AppModule]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__object" of type "*HandlerTypes@AppModule" in function "append"
  Type "Union[*HandlerTypes@AppModule]" cannot be assigned to type "*HandlerTypes@AppModule"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Any ideas how I could work this out? Thanks a lot! Full code below

```
class Dog:
    pass

class Cat:
    pass

class MyFirstDog(Dog):
    pass

class MyFirstCat(Cat):
    pass

class MySecondDog(Dog):
    pass

class MySecondCat(Cat):
    pass

HandlerType1 = Callable[[MyFirstDog, MyFirstCat], Tuple[MyFirstDog, MyFirstCat]]
HandlerType2 = Callable[[MySecondDog, MySecondCat], Tuple[MySecondDog, MySecondCat]]

HandlerTypes = TypeVarTuple('HandlerTypes')

class AppModule(Generic[*HandlerTypes]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.handlers: list[Union[*HandlerTypes]] = []

    def pet_handler(self, handler_func: Union[*HandlerTypes]) -> Union[*HandlerTypes]:
        self.handlers.append(handler_func)
        return handler_func

appmodule = AppModule[HandlerType1, HandlerType2]()

@appmodule.pet_handler
def pet_handler1(a: MyFirstDog, b: MyFirstCat) -> Tuple[MyFirstDog, MyFirstCat]:
    return (a, b)

@appmodule.pet_handler
def pet_handler2(a: MySecondDog, b: MySecondCat) -> Tuple[MySecondDog, MySecondCat]:
    return (a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expected result without using variadic generics:

```
from typing import Tuple, Generic, Callable, Union, TypeVar

class Dog:
    pass

class Cat:
    pass

class MyFirstDog(Dog):
    pass

class MyFirstCat(Cat):
    pass

class MySecondDog(Dog):
    pass

class MySecondCat(Cat):
    pass

HandlerType1 = Callable[[MyFirstDog, MyFirstCat], Tuple[MyFirstDog, MyFirstCat]]
HandlerType2 = Callable[[MySecondDog, MySecondCat], Tuple[MySecondDog, MySecondCat]]
QueryHandlerList = Union[HandlerType1, HandlerType2]

TQueryHandler = TypeVar('TQueryHandler', bound=QueryHandlerList)

class AppModule(Generic[TQueryHandler]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.handlers: list[TQueryHandler] = []

    def pet_handler(self, handler_func: TQueryHandler) -> TQueryHandler:
        self.handlers.append(handler_func)
        return handler_func

appmodule = AppModule[QueryHandlerList]()

@appmodule.pet_handler
def pet_handler1(a: MyFirstDog, b: MyFirstCat) -> Tuple[MyFirstDog, MyFirstCat]:
    return (a, b)

@appmodule.pet_handler
def pet_handler2(a: MySecondDog, b: MySecondCat) -> Tuple[MySecondDog, MySecondCat]:
    return (a, b)
```